# svn overwrite- an erntire folder in repository

Tags: tortoisesvn

In svn Repository having a folder exProject.(which contains all the proj files) .
In my local machine I have my working copy also (versioned one).

How can I overwrite entire folder exProject in svn with code  which I downloaded from somewhere else from my machine.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-overwrite the files on your local working copy with the files you got from somewhere else, then svn commit them.